# How to run a integration test in Spring with @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am trying to learn integration tests with Spring. So I am following this tutorial:

http://www.lucassaldanha.com/unit-and-integration-tests-in-spring-boot/

I am fase a test Class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class GreetingControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void helloTest(){    
        TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
        Hello hello = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/hello", Hello.class);

        Assert.assertEquals(hello.getMessage(), "ola!");
    }
}
```

But when I ***mvn install***, I get this error:

I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/hello": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

So... What am I doing wrong? What I need to do to make my test work?

**Note:** If I run ***mvn spring-boot:run*** the project works fine and I request the end point using any browser.

Comment: I believe you need to inject the `TestRestTemplate`. Either that, or you need to not specify the port, since you're using `RANDOM_PORT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because of the following property in your test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

As per spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.html), it binds the application to a random port. So, while sending the request, there's a chance that the app won't be running on `port` 8080 and hence, you get connection refused error.

If you want to run the app on a particular port, you need to remove `webEnvironment` property and annotate your class with the following:

`@IntegrationTest("server.port=8080")`

Another approach is to get the port and add it into the url, below is the snippet to get the port:

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;

String port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port");
```

Comment: This works with one trick. You have to get the port number with `environment.getProperty("local.server.port")` when sending the requests, not at startup. It's because the server hasn't finished starting up yet.

Answer (score 6):

You can autowire the random port value to a field in the test class if you want to:

```
@LocalServerPort
int port;
```

but you can autowire the restTemplate and you should be able to use it with relative URI without the need to know the port number:

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
public void helloTest(){    
    Hello hello = restTemplate.getForObject("/hello", Hello.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(hello.getMessage(), "ola!");
}
```